# CSS file change after I click "save file" in Wordpress(See pictures)

Tags: css, wordpress

Can anyone explain why the code in class would disappear after I click save file on the tab of Edit CSS in wordpress?

How can I normally add my own css class in wordpress? (the css file is specific for a certain page in Wordpress)

Before I click save file:
[image]
code:

```
   .rect_style {
     stroke:black;
     stroke-width:5;
  }
  .rect_color_1{
      fill:#FFC863;
  }
  .rect_color_2{
      fill:#FFB939;
  }
  .rect_color_3{
      fill:#C58000;
  }
  .rect_color_4{
      fill:#9B6400;
  }
  .rect_obvious{
        opacity:1;
  }
  .rect_blur{
        opacity:0.2;
  }
  .rect_none{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .external1{
      position:relative;
      width: 100px;
  }
  .external2{
      position:relative;
      width: 100px;
  }
```

After I click save file:
[image]

```
.rect_style {
}

.rect_color_1 {
}

.rect_color_2 {
}

.rect_color_3 {
}

.rect_color_4 {
}

.rect_obvious {
    opacity: 1;
}

.rect_blur {
    opacity: .2;
}

.rect_none {
    opacity: 0;
}

.external1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.external2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**From the code, you could notice that it just deletes part of code.**

Comment: 1. It's not a GIF :P 2. It's very hard to know what the problem is given we can't reproduce. 3. This question is off topic because it doesn't deal directly with code. It would be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Logout > Delete Cookies > Login again > Then save and check!

Comment: so it removes the svg stuff? it might be error checking your file before saving and dosent recognise the svg as valid properties